# Change existing email account server

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, email

I am running Galaxy J5 with Android 6 and I need to change server settings for existing email account.

Way used before

*From the Email app, press the menu key, then choose Settings. Pick Account settings, then click the account you want to change on the next screen.
After that, you have to scroll to the bottom to get More settings, and to the bottom again to change the Incoming settings and Outgoing settings.*

Does not work because there is no More settings or settings at all. 
Also settings-accounts-email there are no settings.

Where is this setting hidden please?

Thanks

Comment: If you want to change your connection from IMAP to POP3, you must delete the email account and recreate it as a POP3 account.

Comment: That is something I would like to avoid. Anyway if I need to change something like signature or sync frequency, where is it?

Comment: Gmail > settings >choose account > change sync frequency,signature and other settings

Comment: Unfortunately this works only for gmail account. I have some others + one exhange which are not available at gmail app

Comment: Settings > account> you can see other accounts like Yahoo, Dropbox etc. You should find your exchange app there. Either you should be able to change from there or from within the app. I don't use exchange. In any case, please edit your question to make it specific with examples so that others can pitch in